# pst-3dplot fails - how do I resolve this issue?

Tags: pst-3dplot

In the past I used pst-3dplot package to generate nice geometric figures in pdf format. Two days ago I tried to run a TeX recompile and the compile failed as the log file complains that the "\pstThreeDLine(0,0,0)(10,10,10)" (and subsequent other line commands) is broken and the error is

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks
> _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
> l.49        \pstThreeDLine(
> 0,0,0)(10,10,10)
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed.

I have an updated openSuse Linux Leap 15.5 system, currently updated software, and the TeXlive modules seem current. I reloaded the "pst-3dplot" software as well as the "xkeyvalue" module too, but things are just flat broken.

How can I proceed on determining the real problem here? Thank you.

Comment: you can not use pdflatex with pstricks, use latex or lualatex

Comment: David, you are absolutely 100% correct. I had to specifically force TeXStudio to compile using normal latex, then things worked correctly, except that I had to then force a dvi file --> ps conversion, then a ps --> pdf conversion which were 2 extra steps. But I appreciate you alerting me to this requirement. My issue is closed